# LiveDate version 2

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, datetime, ajax, error-handling

`LiveDate` has the ability to display the current date either by asynchronously fetching the time from a server or by just using the client system date. It's only as accurate / reliable as the source being used.

It's pretty much finished, but before I definitely considered it that I'd like to get a full review of it.

Specifically I'd also appreciate a review on my error handling and the way I'm importing the dependencies into the IIFE by just passing in `window`. And `sendAjaxRequest` since this function dependency is optional depending on which method is used to update the time.

Any suggestions for improvement are welcome!

**LiveDate.js**

```
var LiveDate = (function (global) {
    'use strict';

    function LiveDate(settings) {
        this.element = settings.element;

        this.timeUrl = settings.timeUrl || null;
        this.format = settings.format || LiveDate.formats.ISO8601;
        this.offset = settings.offset || 0;
        this.errorHtml = settings.errorHtml || 'LiveDate Error';

        this.weekdayNames = {
            'long': settings.weekdayNames && settings.weekdayNames['long'] ? settings.weekdayNames['long'] : [
                'Sunday',
                'Monday',
                'Tuesday',
                'Wednesday',
                'Thursday',
                'Friday',
                'Saturday'
            ],
            'short': settings.weekdayNames && settings.weekdayNames['short'] ? settings.weekdayNames['short'] : [
                'Sun',
                'Mon',
                'Tue',
                'Wed',
                'Thu',
                'Fri',
                'Sat'
            ]
        };

        this.monthNames = {
            'long': settings.monthNames && settings.monthNames['long'] ? settings.monthNames['long'] : [
                'January',
                'February',
                'March',
                'April',
                'May',
                'June',
                'July',
                'August',
                'September',
                'October',
                'November',
                'December'
            ],
            'short': settings.monthNames && settings.monthNames['short'] ? settings.monthNames['short'] : [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        };

        this.start();
    }

    LiveDate.prototype.start = function () {
        var self = this;

        if (!this.timeUrl) {
            this._tickIntervalId = global.setInterval((function tick() {
                self._date = new global.Date(new global.Date().getTime() + self.offset);

                displayDate();

                return tick;
            }()), 200);

            return;
        }

        global.sendAjaxRequest({
            url: this.timeUrl,
            headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' },
            cacheDocument: false,
            successHandler: successHandler,
            networkErrorHandler: networkErrorHandler
        });

        function successHandler(xhr) {
            if (!(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299)) {
                displayError();

                throw {
                    name: 'AjaxRequestFetchError',
                    context: 'Fetching the document from: ' + self.timeUrl + '.',
                    problem: 'HTTP ' + xhr.status + ' was returned but expected HTTP 200.',
                    solution: 'Double check the URL and make sure it\'s reachable.',
                    toString: function () { return this.name; }
                };
            }

            var requestTime = new global.Date().getTime(),
                previousTime = new global.Date().getTime(),
                serverTime = parseInt(xhr.responseText, 10);

            self._tickIntervalId = global.setInterval((function () {
                tick();

                return tick;
            }()), 200);

            function tick() {
                var NET_REINIT_WAIT_PERIOD = 10000;

                var currentTime = new global.Date().getTime();

                // Detecting client's system date changes to keep ours unaffected.
                // Interval delay increment taken into account as well (+500 ms).
                if ((currentTime - previousTime) < 0 || (currentTime - previousTime) >= 1500) {
                    self.stop();

                    // Introducing a delay particularly for PC's that've just been awoken to
                    // try and prevent an AjaxRequestFetchError from being thrown due to their
                    // Internet connection not being reinitialized yet.
                    global.setTimeout(function () {
                        self.start();
                    }, NET_REINIT_WAIT_PERIOD);

                    return;
                }

                self._date = new global.Date(serverTime + currentTime - requestTime + self.offset);

                displayDate();

                previousTime = currentTime;
            }
        }

        function networkErrorHandler(xhr) {
            displayError();

            throw {
                name: 'AjaxRequestNetworkError',
                context: 'Sending an AJAX request to: ' + self.timeUrl + '.',
                problem: 'Some type of network error or fetch termination occurred. (Error ' + xhr.status + ')',
                solution: 'For the solution, analyse the network level for problems.',
                toString: function () { return this.name; }
            };
        }

        function displayError() {
            self.element.innerHTML = self.errorHtml;
        }

        function displayDate() {
            self.element.innerHTML = self.formatAs(self.format);
        }
    };

    LiveDate.prototype.formatAs = function (format) {
        var self = this;

        function padNumber(number, width, character) {
            number = '' + number;
            character = character || 0;

            if (number.length < width) {
                return new global.Array(width - number.length + 1).join(character) + number;
            }

            return number;
        }

        var dateFormatter = {
            /* DAY */
            // Day of the month with leading zeros (01 to 31).
            d: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCDate(), 2);
            },

            // Short textual representation of the day of the week (Mon).
            D: function () {
                return self.weekdayNames['short'][self._date.getUTCDay()];
            },

            // Day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31).
            j: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCDate();
            },

            // Long textual representation of the day of the week (Monday).
            l: function () {
                return self.weekdayNames['long'][self._date.getUTCDay()];
            },

            /* MONTH */
            // Long textual representation of the month (January).
            F: function () {
                return self.monthNames['long'][self._date.getUTCMonth()];
            },

            // Numeric representation of the month with leading zeros (01 to 12).
            m: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCMonth() + 1, 2);
            },

            // Short textual representation of the month (Jan).
            M: function () {
                return self.monthNames['short'][self._date.getUTCMonth()];
            },

            // Numeric representation of the month without leading zeros (1 to 12).
            n: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCMonth() + 1;
            },

            /* YEAR */
            // Short numeric representation of the year (15).
            y: function () {
                return ('' + self._date.getUTCFullYear()).slice(-2);
            },

            // Long numeric representation of the year (2015).
            Y: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCFullYear();
            },

            /* TIME */
            // Lowercase ante meridiem (a.m.) or post meridiem (p.m.).
            a: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCHours() < 12 ? 'a.m.' : 'p.m.';
            },

            // Uppercase ante meridiem (A.M.) or post meridiem (P.M.).
            A: function () {
                return this.a().toUpperCase();
            },

            // 12-hour format of the hour without leading zeros (1 to 12).
            g: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCHours() % 12 || 12;
            },

            // 24-hour format of the hour without leading zeros (0 to 23).
            G: function () {
                return self._date.getUTCHours();
            },

            // 12-hour format of the hour with leading zeros (01 to 12).
            h: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCHours() % 12 || 12, 2);
            },

            // 24-hour format of the hour with leading zeros (00 to 23).
            H: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCHours(), 2);
            },

            // Minutes with leading zeros (00 to 59).
            i: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCMinutes(), 2);
            },

            // Seconds with leading zeros (00 to 59).
            s: function () {
                return padNumber(self._date.getUTCSeconds(), 2);
            },

            /* TIMEZONE */
            // Hour and minute difference to UTC without colon in-between and with leading zeros (+0000).
            O: function () {
                var sign = self.offset < 0 ? '-' : '+',
                    hours = global.Math.floor(global.Math.abs(self.offset) / 3600000),
                    minutes = self.offset / 3600000 % 1 * 60;

                return sign + padNumber(hours, 2) + padNumber(minutes, 2);
            },

            // Hour and minute difference to UTC with colon in-between and leading zeros (+00:00).
            P: function () {
                var O = this.O();

                return O.substr(0, 3) + ':' + O.substr(3);
            }
        };

        return format.replace(/(\\?)([a-z])/gi, function (match, isEscaped, character) {
            return !isEscaped && dateFormatter[character] ? dateFormatter[character]() : character;
        });
    };

    LiveDate.prototype.getTime = function () {
        return this._date.getTime();
    };

    LiveDate.prototype.stop = function () {
        global.clearInterval(this._tickIntervalId);

        delete this._tickIntervalId;
    };

    LiveDate.formats = {
        ATOM: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP',
        ISO8601: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP',
        RSS: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O',
        RFC822: 'D, d M y H:i:s O',
        RFC1036: 'D, d M y H:i:s O',
        RFC1123: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O',
        RFC2822: 'D, d M Y H:i:s O',
        RFC3339: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP',
        W3C: 'Y-m-d\\TH:i:sP'
    };

    return LiveDate;
}(window));
```

**Example**

```
// Server Synced Date
var serverLiveDate = new LiveDate({
    timeUrl: 'time.php',
    element: document.getElementById('server-date'),
    format: 'l j F Y - <\\b>H:i:s</\\b>',
    offset: 720000 // UTC+2
});

// Client System Synced Date
var clientLiveDate = new LiveDate({
    element: document.getElementById('client-date')
});
```

Comment: I don't understand about the practical use of this code, can you explain a typical use case?

Comment: @Vignesh Isn't it somewhat self-explanatory?

Comment: The code is pretty self explanatory, But I haven't came across a  situation where I needed to fetch time from the server (beginner). So I am curious about a real use case.

Comment: @Vignesh Because JavaScript's `Date` object is only as reliable as the client system date, which you have no control of. So if their system date is inaccurate, so will the time returned by `Date` be. If you need a solution that displays the "**real**" time that's not affected by how the client system date is set, you can get the date from a (reliable) server. For instance, you might have a service that displays different live dates from all over the world. But if you rely on the client system date and it's not set correctly, **every** date shown by your service will be incorrect as well.

Comment: Does this take into account that the browser and server may be in different time zones? If it doesn't, maybe it isn't very useful (I'm still a little unsure about the use case for this module).

Comment: Scenario: the user is in GMT+1, the server is in GMT-7, the code is configured to use the servers time and the format is HH:MM. Lets say the local time is 20:00 at the user, yet the server claims it is 12:00. Thats just weird.

Comment: @MichaelZedeler The server returns a Unix timestamp, and Unix timestamps are universal. A Unix timestamp of `1430044657` would be the same across the entire world, so it doesn't matter what time zone either party is in. The timezone offset,  `offset`, of the client is applied to the fetched Unix timestamp resulting in a correctly localized date.

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

- Your default settings should sit in an object and be referred to with `this.something = settings.something || defaults.something`. It just makes the code read better.
- The use of `var self = this` should be superseded by calls to `.bind(this)` or `.call(this)` on the function object. (`global.setInterval(function tick() { ... }.call(this))`).
- There's an implicit dependency on `sendAjaxRequest`. Pass it as an argument to the IIFE.
- You have too many `tick` functions. It's unclear which is used where without digging into the scope.
- Always throw instances of Error. If you need to implement a custom error type, do so.
- Don't handle the error (`displayError()`) and then throw an error. Throw the error, and handle it in the relevant `catch` block.

Also, what's the need for `sendAjaxRequest` here? How does it do things better than just making a new `XMLHttpRequest` object and working with that?

A few WTFs when going over your code:

```
global.setInterval((function () {
    tick(); // wat

    return tick; // WAT
}()), 200);
```

and

```
function successHandler(xhr) { // Success!
    if (!(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299)) {
        displayError(); // Doesn't look very successful to me...
```

and

```
function networkErrorHandler(xhr) {
    displayError(); // Deja vuu. DRY please.
```